# PHP time() shows incorrect time, an hour back

Tags: php, date, timezone

I've converted `time()` into hours, minutes and seconds using `gmdate("H:i:s", time());`.

**Problem:**

However, when I echo it out it shows the time an hour back. Right now it's:

> 15:05

But the `gmdate()` shows:

> 14:05

Why is this happening?

**Edit:** I have set a timezone for Europe/London.

Comment: you need to set a [timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: I did that already.

Comment: could your server's time be set wrongly ?

Comment: Because `gmdate` shows " the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)."?

Comment: London is currently observing BST, which is 1 hour ahead of GMT. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = time();
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date('H:i:s', $time);
```

Your time zone is incorrect. It is `Europe/London` not the other way around. Also, London is not currently under Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), it is only under GMT during the winter months. You originally used `gmdate()`, which is basically identical to `date()` only the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time(GMT), which is currently one hour behind London.

Comment: I actually wrote Europe/London. I just made a typo on the question. This doesn't work.

Comment: What is the return value you are getting from `time()`? Also, please post your actual code.

Comment: The return value is 1595603541. What do you mean actual code? I did that

Comment: OK, that isn't what I posted. I posted `date()`, not `gmdate()`. Also, post your actual timezone function.

Comment: I tried doing date, like the other answer suggested. I already told you it didn't work. My timezone function is `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`

Comment: Then there is no reason it should not work. Where are you reading the output from? What is your default runtime configuration for `date.timezone`?

Comment: Do you have a timezone environment variable?

Comment: I don't know what that is

Comment: What is the return value if you call ‘date_default_timezone_get’ as opposed to ‘set’?

Comment: “What do you mean actual code?” If you post the actual lines of code from your IDE, it may be easier to spot what has gone awry.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? Where is the first return value that is not the expected value?

Answer (score 0):

`gmdate()` is a function which returns Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

You can use `date()` function for local time in your timezone. Also you can set your timezone by using `date_default_timezone_set('your timezone');`

Comment: can you add your timezone with `date_default_timezone_set('your timezone');` befor using 'date() function. You can find your timezone here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: did you use this function like this at the beginning of your code? ´date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');´

Comment: Yes. I said so in the question.